# How to make Inner shadow in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to make View's (Text, Button, etc) Inner shadow in SwiftUI

There is Outer shadow but there is no Inner shadow in SwiftUI

What I want to make is Neumorphism UI using SwiftUI

[image]

> Image from "Neumorphism in user interfaces" by *Michal Malewicz*

I'd like to make button pressed UI

but I don't know where to start to make inner shadow

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/hirokimu/EMTNeumorphicView it’s for UIKit, but may give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what I did to create an inner shadow like the one in the picture. I created it in another swiftui file and just called in in my main content view but you can display it however you'd like.

I created a Button in a ZStack only because I first recreated it with a rounded rectangle but I think this would would in a HStack or VStack as well just haven't tried them. To create the inner shadow I created an overlay and clipped the shadows to the shape.

```
ZStack{
        
        Button(action: {}){
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .padding(25)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 52/255, green: 57/255, blue: 133/255))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .stroke(Color(red: 236/255, green: 234/255, blue: 235/255), 
                                lineWidth: 4)
                        .shadow(color: Color(red: 192/255, green: 189/255, blue: 191/255), 
                                radius: 3, x: 5, y: 5)
                        .clipShape(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        )
                        .shadow(color: Color.white, radius: 2, x: -2, y: -2)
                        .clipShape(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        )
                )
                .background(Color(red: 236/255, green: 234/255, blue: 235/255))
                .cornerRadius(20)
        }
```

The end result looked like this:
[image]

You can play around with the colors and the shadows to get exactly what you want but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. It would be even more helpful if you could format the overlay code so it fits in the window and add some comments to help readers understand why it works. In particular, what the `clipShape` calls are doing isn't necessarily obvious to reader. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I copy/pasted this code and the white inner shadow is being prevented from fully reaching the edge by the dark inner shadow.. did apple change the way this works?

Answer (score 8):

### iOS 16+

There is now a new `ShapeStyle` called `shadow`:

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shapestyle/shadow(_:)-swift.method) - the following example creates a circle filled with the current foreground style that uses an inner shadow:

```
Circle().fill(.shadow(.inner(radius: 1, y: 1)))
```

> In most contexts the current style is the foreground, but not always. For example, when setting the value of the background style, that becomes the current implicit style.

```
Circle()
    .fill(.shadow(.inner(radius: 1, y: 1)))
    .foregroundStyle(.red)
```

Comment: This works great on macOS as well! 

Comment: This works perfectly on iOS

Answer (score 8):

## iOS 16+ only

### For Buttons

You could use a SwiftUI shape as background.

Use `.fill(.shadow(.inner(radius: 1, y: 1)))` for inner shadow.

The `.foregroundColor` of the shape is the background color of the button.

### Here's my example using pawello2222's answer

For a **RoundedRectangle** Button same as the question

```
Button(action: {}){
        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .padding(25)
            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 52/255, green: 57/255, blue: 133/255))
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                    .fill(
                        .shadow(.inner(color: Color(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255),radius: 3, x:3, y: 3))
                        .shadow(.inner(color: .white, radius: 3, x: -3, y: -3))
                    )
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 236/255, green: 234/255, blue: 235/255)))
          }
}
```

[image: RoundedRectangle Button]

For a **Circle Button**

```
Button(action: {}){
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .padding(25)
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 52/255, green: 57/255, blue: 133/255))
                .background(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(
                            .shadow(.inner(color: Color(red: 197/255, green: 197/255, blue: 197/255),radius: 5, x:3, y: 3))
                            .shadow(.inner(color: .white, radius:5, x: -3, y: -3))
                        )
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 236/255, green: 234/255, blue: 235/255)))
}
```

[image: Circle Button]